# Voodoo with DOS Batch files

Tags: visual-studio, installation, batch-file

I've created a simple `batch file` that kicks off my ***.msi** installer within our company, creating a log file of the process, then displays the log file after the installer has completed.

**installAndLog.bat:**

```
msiexec.exe /i "\\FileServer2\setup.msi" /l*v "C:\setupLog.txt"
"C:\setupLog.txt"
```

It works, but there are two (2) glitches that annoy me:

- The black console box shows in the background the whole time the installer is running and the log file is being displayed. **Q1: How do I hide that?**

and

- The console box will not close until the log file is no longer being viewed (i.e. notepad.exe is closed). **Q2: Can I call the text file in a new process and simply exit?**

I was a DOS lover back in the day, but that was too many years ago.

Comment: For the second, say `start C:\setupLog.txt`, which backgrounds the process. You can also add the famous `@echo off` to the top of the file to make it less chatty.

Comment: For the first, if you can't arrange to start the batch file minimised one workaround I've used is for the first batch file to `start /min` a second batch file which then invokes the long operation.

Comment: @Neil: Sounds like a hack ...but then, it **is** a batch file! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can hide the console window when running a batch file.  However you can use vbscript instead which will by default not create a console window.

Take the below and put it in a file with a .vbs extension:

```
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

wshShell.Run "msiexec.exe /i ""\\FileServer2\setup.msi"" /l*v ""C:\setupLog.txt""", 1, true
wshShell.Run "C:\setupLog.txt"
```

All the double double quotes are there because the entire command must be surrounded by "'s and doubling them escapes them.  The the documentation for [WshShell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Any special permissions required to run vbscript? (new territory for me). Also, what are the parameters on the end for (1, true)?

Comment: @jp2code - no special permissions needed.  The 1, true mean show the application and wait for exit.  Take a look at the documentation link for  WshShell.Run in the answer.

Comment: If this works (not at work at the moment), I'll ditch the old DOS scripts. Wished there were a cshShell (C language version). VB language just makes my skin crawl a little.

Comment: You can write JScript instead of VBScript. The former has syntax similar to C.

Comment: @Alexey: Where would I find how to write that in JScript? For Example: I'm getting `Error JS1135: Variable 'CreateObject' has not been declared`

Comment: @jp2code It's there in the MSDN: [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Usually there are examples for both VBScript and JScript. `CreateObject` corresponds to `new ActiveXObject()` in JScript; parenthesis are required in function calls, and semicolons at the end of statements.

Answer (score 3):

Q1 - AFAIK you can't really hide the *console* window.

Q2 - Use the `start` command. This will launch the specified program (notepad) outside of the shell. It will also prevent the shell from waiting until the application closes to continue processing the batch script.

You might be better off changing the batch script to launch the MSI installer using the `start` command and having the installer launch notepad to view the log file once installation is complete.

Comment: Great! `@echo off` will prevent my verbiage from displaying on the screen, but what would hide or minimize the *Console Window*?

Comment: There are no commands in Windows shell which can hide or minimize a window, but you can write one. Or you can write a program which launches MSI with the required options, waits for it to complete and then starts Notepad. Or program these actions in JScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get these batch windows away, you'll have to switch over to something else. One simple alternative could be one of the scripting languages supported by the windows scripting host.
Or you try HTA (HTML applications) see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) and [here](http://www.hyperwrite.com/Articles/html_applications.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Run the dos script as a different user by scheduled task or as a service.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, for the benefit of others