# JScript or JQuery in Windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a C# developer using Visual Studio, but I'm interested in creating some **JScript** or **JQuery** programs to run on our Windows machines. There is obviously a learning curve I've got to get over.

- Will **JQuery** run on a PC, or does it have to run on a web page?

I'd like to start by mimicing a **VBScript** I was presented with not long ago:

```
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

wshShell.Run "msiexec.exe /i ""\\CPFS2\Share Files\package.msi"" /l*v ""C:\install.txt""", 1, true
wshShell.Run "C:\install.log"
```

Can this be done with either **JScript** or **JQuery**?

What are good search tool terms to help me locate help on this topic? (*JScript*, *Windows* is not producing much)

Comment: JQuery *could* run but you would lose 90% of it's functionality when not in a browser environment. What do your JS scripts need to do? Look into node.js.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481731/any-tutorials-for-using-json-jscript-and-jquery

Comment: What do you want to use jQuery to do?

Comment: if the webpage is in the pc . jquery & JS will run in that local web page in that pc .

Comment: @Xeon06 & Diodeus: Currently, I'm looking to launch my MSI Installer with the switches shown in the VBScript example. I'll move forward from there.

Comment: Ok well jQuery has nothing to do with that. It's a JavaScript library for manipulating web pages.

Comment: Ah. Then the comment presented to me by Alexey in SO question #7046252 was wrong, then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046252/voodoo-with-dos-batch-files ? I'm not seeing any mention of jQuery

Comment: No, no mention of JQuery. He mentioned JScript, and reading up on JScript brought me to JQuery. I thought I might be able to do even more JScript stuff if I leveraged JQuery ...but apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be the JScript you're looking for.

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
shell.run("whatever");
```

I can't test it right now, but even if it works, I would really recommend you look into node.js instead of using JScript.

Comment: **ActiveXObject**! That's what I was missing! So, any idea how to prevent Windows from popping up it's little annoying dialog box after running one of these scripts that says, *"This program might not have installed correctly"*?

Comment: No clue. Once more, for many reasons which I'm sure you'll discover yourself, liek you just did, I'd refrain from using JScript.

Comment: In Sorpigal's answer, he used `WScript.CreateObject`. How is this different from `ActiveXObject`? Is the overhead the same?

Comment: Haven't the slightest idea. This article might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/06/01/145686.aspx I honnestly wouldn't be concerned about the overhead of something like that unless you have problems

Answer (score 3):

**JScript** is just what Microsoft calls its implementation of [ECMAScript](http://www.ecmascript.org/). ECMAScript is more commonly known as JavaScript, though this is technically improper. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a JavaScript library designed to make manipulating the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_DOM_and_JavaScript) easier. While it can be used to some extent outside of a web browser it doesn't make as much sense to do so.

What it sounds like you want to do is run JavaScript scripts locally on a Windows box instead of VBScript scripts. In either case this is done by using the [Windows Scripting Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). JavaScript doesn't offer much intrinsic support for I/O but instead relies on the environment in which it is run. In a web browser it primarily intereacts with the DOM but in the WSH it will interact with the same objects that are provided to VBScript.

The equivalent WSH-based JavaScript to yuor VBScript example would be

```
var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");

wshShell.Run("msiexec.exe /i \"\\\\CPFS2\\Share Files\\package.msi\\\" /l*v \"C:\install.txt\"", 1, true);

wshShell.Run("C:\install.log");
```

As you can see it's nearly identical, because in both cases you are just scripting the Windows Scripting Host.

There is no "jQuery" equivalent of this, because jQuery is just a set of libraries you can use from JavaScript and nothing being done here would find any of its features useful.

Comment: +1. So, to learn more on what all is available with techniques like these, should I search for `Windows Scripting Host` or `How to script Windows Scripting Host`?

Comment: @jp2code: Yes. Generally you'll find information and examples on WSH+VBScript, but you can likely figure out the JS equivalent from that. All of the objects and methods from the WSH are the same and only the calling syntax differs.

Comment: In Xeon06's answer, he used `ActiveXObject`. How is this different from `WScript.CreateObject`? Is the overhead the same?

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is a [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) library that helps with manipulation of the structure of web pages, and as such is useless for desktop applications. I think you're confusing the term 'JQuery' (a library) with JavaScript (a scripting language).

If your question is whether you can use JavaScript or JScript (which is Microsofts variety of JavaScript) for Windows scripting, the short version is: yes you can. You can run [JScript scripts right from Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yyeyb0a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and you can create Windows PowerShell cmdlets using JScript.NET.

Comment: +1. I think this is what I'm after. I use the term `JQuery` instead of `JavaScript` because the former would appear (to me) to be more suitable to replacing `VBScript` code for Windows scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Check jQuery for admins http://code.google.com/p/jquery-for-admins/

Plus you can use Mongoose + WSH as cgi to show nice HTML report about executing admin tasks.